# Cannot remove rect upon collision in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a game using javascript. The function drawItems draws 5 rectangles which are meant to resemble coins. When the player collides with the coin thanks to the itemCollision function (which works), the coin should disappear. I have tried different ways of doing this such as assigning a status which should only allow the rect() method to draw if the status is 1. That didn't work. I also tried deleting the array item and that didnt work either. I also tried another way of using an if statement with the clearRect function at the itemX and itemY positions but to no avail. The updateGameArea method is called in a setInterval function with a 20ms timeout and I understand that in the latter the item is cleared however it is redrawn on the next loop however I have no idea how to get around this. Any suggestions please?

```
let itemWidth = 15;
let itemHeight = 15;
let itemX = 150;
let itemY = 600;

 items = {
        x:0,
        y:0,
        status : 1
    };

    function drawItems() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            itemX = i*100;
             items[i] = {x: 0, y: 0, status: 1};
             console.log(items[i].status);
            if (items[i].status === 1){
                items[i].x = itemX;
                items[i].y = itemY;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight);
                ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();

            }
            // console.log(itemX + " " + player.x);

        }
    }

    function itemCollision(){
        for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            var b = items[i];
            if (b.status === 1) {
                if (player.x > b.x && player.x < b.x + itemWidth + 10 && player.y > b.y && player.y < b.y + itemHeight) {
                    b.status = 0;
                    delete items[i];
                }else b.status = 1;

            }
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
        movePlayer();
        // console.log(platform.y + " and " + player.y);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, gameAreaWidth, gameAreaHeight);
        drawItems();
        itemCollision();
```

Comment: Note: I have already tried searching for ways of getting around this but found nothing... Apologies if this haas been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `for` loop, you set `items[i].status` to be `1` with this code: `items[i] = {x: 0, y: 0, status: 1};`. And immediately after, you check `if(items[i].status === 1)`. Of course, the condition of the `if` statement is always true, so the rectangle always gets drawn.

Keep the array initialization part in a separate function, and call it only once, before the game begins. Do something like this:

```
const items = [];                     // empty array

function gameInitialize() {           // call it before the game begins
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        items.push({x: 0, y: 0, status: 1}); 
    }
}

function drawItems() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        itemX = i*100;                // this line is a bit suspicious, maybe it does not belong here, I don't know
        if (items[i].status === 1) {
            items[i].x = itemX;
            items[i].y = itemY;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(itemX, itemY, itemWidth, itemHeight);
            ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, do not use `delete` on array items (unless you really know what you're doing, but even then, better not to). To remove the i-th item from an array `items`, you can use `items.splice(i, 1);`. However, you don't need to do this with your status setting approach.

Comment: Nevermind had an error in my code and finally got it to work... thanks a million!